# Lane-emden solutions using RK4 (hard-coded)

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I'm working on finding an plotting solutions to the Lane-Emden equation for values `n=[0,6]`, in intervals of `1/2`. I'm new to Python, and can't seem to figure out how to use RK4 to make this work. Please help!

[image: LE Solutions]

Current progress.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Pow: 'int' and 'list' on line 37 in main.py
```

The error just appeared after I added in the equations defined as `r2`, `r3`, `r4` and `k2`, `k3`, `k4`.

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
theta0 = 1
phi0 = 0
step = 0.01
xi0 = 0
xi_max = 100

theta = theta0
phi = phi0
xi = xi0 + step

Theta = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
Phi = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
Xi = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

for i in n:
    Theta[i].append(theta)
    Phi[i].append(phi)
    Xi[i].append(xi)
 
def dTheta_dXi(phi,xi): #r1
    return -phi/xi**2
    
def r2(phi,xi):
    return dTheta_dXi(phi+step,xi+step*dTheta_dXi(phi,xi))

def r3(phi,xi):
    return dTheta_dXi(phi+step,xi+step*r2(phi,xi))
    
def r4(phi,xi):
    return dTheta_dXi(phi+step,xi+step*r3(phi,xi))

def dPhi_dXi(theta,xi,n): #k1
    return theta**(n)*xi**2
    
def k2(theta,xi,n):
    return dPhi_dXi(theta+step,xi+step*dPhi_dXi(theta,xi,n),n)

def k3(theta,xi,n):
    return dPhi_dXi(theta+step,xi+step*k2(theta,xi,n),n)
    
def k4(theta,xi,n):
    return dPhi_dXi(theta+step,xi+step*k3(theta,xi,n),n)
    
for i in n: 
    while xi < xi_max:
        if theta < 0:
            break
        dTheta = (step/6)*(dTheta_dXi(phi,xi)+2*r2(phi,xi)+2*r3(phi,xi)+r4(phi,xi))
        dPhi = (step/6)*(dPhi_dXi(theta,xi,i/2.)+2*k2(theta,xi,n)+2*k3(theta,xi,n)+k4(theta,xi,n))
        theta += dTheta
        phi += dPhi
        xi += step
        Theta[i].append(theta)
        Phi[i].append(phi)
        Xi[i].append(xi)
    print i/2., round(xi,4), round(dTheta_dXi(phi,xi),4), round(xi/3./dTheta_dXi(phi,xi),4), round(1./(4*np.pi*(i/2.+1))/dTheta_dXi(phi,xi)**2,4)
    theta = theta0
    phi = phi0
    xi = xi0 + step
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This would greatly increase your odds of getting the right help for your problem. Also, specific to your question, you may want to have a look at [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html).

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, norok2! I hope the above helps?

Comment: That's certainly more informative, but perhaps you also want to include what are you expecting from the above code. It looks like you trying, to some extent, to replicate [`scipy.integrate.RK45()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45) . Have you checked out that function?

Comment: Sure. I've added an image of the expected graph, under the link [1]. And you're absolutely right, this is the function expected. However, I'm trying to hard code it, rather than exploit the inbuilt function.

Comment: OK. Perhaps you could integrate all this information in the question (including the title, e.g. that you would like to implement RK4 from scratch). I would also suggest you to improve the formatting of your question. Regarding your code, the specific problem you are stuck with is that `xi` in `dPhi_dXi()` is a `list` instead of a number as you would like to do. In general, why do you define `n`, `Theta`, `Phi`, `Xi` like lists of lists?

Comment: Thank you for your advice regarding the format of questions, as well as with the question itself. I tried to define n, and the associated objects, as lists in order to combine the solutions into a single graph for multiple n values.

Comment: I am sorry, I had it wrong before. It is not `xi` passed as a list, but `n`.
When you compute `dTheta` and `dPhi` you use `n` instead of `i` when calling `k2`, `k3` and `k4`. Aside from that, you should consider improving your code a bit (e.g. no code for the plotting is reported, use Python3, `n` can be defined using a `range`, encapsulate your code in function, follow a clearer coding style like [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). Also, the question should be better formulated. My suggestion would avoid the error, but I would not know if the code solves the Lane-Emden eqn.

Comment: Thanks, norok! I think the n vs i problem is one of the major issues of the code.I'll definitely work on that. I would have liked to use "range", but I couldn't seem to make it accept non-integer values.

Comment: Simply using `n = range(14)` instead of what you have right now, would do the trick, although I would do `n = 14` and then use `range(n)` in the looping.

Comment: This does look a lot better. Thank you! I'm going to try tinker on this, given your input. Hopefully, I'll come back to you with a solution. I really appreciate your help : )

Answer (score 1):

#### Using RK4 for coupled systems

If one understands a first-order system as a vector-valued system working with vector states, then the scalar version of RK4

```
k1 = f(x,y)
k2 = f(x+0.5*h, y+0.5*h*k1)
k3 = f(x+0.5*h, y+0.5*h*k2)
k4 = f(x+h, y+h*k3)
x,y = x+h, y+h/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
```

can also directly be used for the vector case. Sometimes it appears educational to implement this component-wise. While in mathematical texts it is preferred to use one-letter variable names, possibly with sub- or superscripts, the variables in the code of programs usually are multi-lettered. So instead of `r2` and `k2` it would be more descriptive to use `k2_Theta` and `k2_Phi`.

Then it becomes rather intuitive that the state used to evaluate the `k3` components has the arguments `theta+0.5*step*k2_Theta` and `phi+0.5*step*k2_Phi`.

`k2_Xi` etc. is always `1` for the independent variable, so the value for the 3rd stage is simply `xi+0.5*step`.

#### Implementation details RK4

The values of `k1` etc. are fixed inside the step and result from the evaluation of the derivatives function. It makes absolutely no sense to declare them as functions themselves. That is, the RK4 step specialized to this situation becomes just

```
def RK4_update(theta, phi, xi, step, n):
    k1_Theta = dTheta_dXi(phi, xi)
    k1_Phi = dPhi_dXi(theta, xi, n)
    k2_Theta = dTheta_dXi(phi+0.5*step*k1_Phi, xi+0.5*step)
    k2_Phi = dPhi_dXi(theta+0.5*step*k1_Theta, xi+0.5*step, n)
    k3_Theta = dTheta_dXi(phi+0.5*step*k2_Phi, xi+0.5*step)
    k3_Phi = dPhi_dXi(theta+0.5*step*k2_Theta, xi+0.5*step, n)
    k4_Theta = dTheta_dXi(phi+step*k3_Phi, xi+step)
    k4_Phi = dPhi_dXi(theta+step*k3_Theta, xi+step, n)
    dTheta = (step/6)*(k1_Theta+2*k2_Theta+2*k3_Theta+k4_Theta)
    dPhi = (step/6)*(k1_Phi+2*k2_Phi+2*k3_Phi+k4_Phi)
    return dTheta, dPhi
```

#### On the singularity of the Lane-Emden equation

For the solution to exist at `xi=0` one needs at least that `phi ~ xi^k` with `k>=2`. This gives that `theta` is almost constant, which in turn leads to an integration `phi = theta0^n*xi^3/3` which then in the other equation gives `theta = theta0 - theta0^n*xi^2/6`. This allows to take the first step away from the singularity without using the numerical method.

```
xi = step 
theta, phi = theta0 - theta0**n*xi**2/6, theta0**n*xi**3/3
Xi[i] = [0, xi]
Theta[i] = [theta0, theta]
Phi[i] = [0, phi]
```

Then the main loop can be written as

```
for i in range(N): 
    n = i/2
    xi = step 
    theta, phi = theta0 - theta0**n*xi**2/6, theta0**n*xi**3/3
    Xi[i] = [0, xi]
    Theta[i] = [theta0, theta]
    Phi[i] = [0, phi]
    while xi < xi_max:
        if theta < 0:
            break
        dTheta, dPhi = RK4_update(theta,phi,xi,step,n)
        theta += dTheta
        phi += dPhi
        xi += step
        Theta[i].append(theta)
        Phi[i].append(phi)
        Xi[i].append(xi)
```

Then plotting with

```
for i in range(N):
    plt.plot(Xi[i],Theta[i], label=f"n={i/2}")
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

results in

[image: solution plots]

Trick used: To avoid rational powers of negative values, replace `theta**n` with `theta*abs(theta)**(n-1)` or similar continuations.

---

#### Old contents

You should once again explore what update goes where. `xi` is the independent variable and thus only gets updates `0.5*step` and `step`, the updates of `theta` use the derivatives `dTheta_dXi` and similarly `phi` is updated using the slopes `dPhi_dXi`

```
def r2(phi,xi):
    return dTheta_dXi(phi+0.5*step*dPhi_dXi(theta,xi,n),xi+0.5*step)

def k2(theta,xi,n):
    return dPhi_dXi(theta+0.5*step*dTheta_dXi(phi,xi),xi+0.5*step,n)

def r3(phi,xi):
    return dTheta_dXi(phi+0.5*step*k2(theta,xi,n),xi+0.5*step)
```

etc.

Now one can see that due to the coupled nature of the equation you need both `theta` and `phi` as arguments everywhere. Further, even if that works in the end you end up computing many of the values multiple times where assembling everything in one loop only requires one computation.