# Runge-Kutta method to solve Lane-Emden equation

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I am trying to obtain a code that will give me the numerical solutions of the Lane-Edmen equation, using the Runge-Kutta 4 steps method.
I am not super into C++ and therefore there must be something I am missing, since the code is running, but the data calculated are clearly wrong. Untill now I am considering only the case n=0, for simplicity.
Could you check it and give me an opinion, please?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#define Nmax 400

using namespace std;

void RK4Step(double x, double *Y, double (*dYdx)(double, double), double (*dZdx)(double, double, double), double dx, int neq);

double dYdx(double x, double Y);

double dZdx(double x, double Y, double Z);



int main(){

    cout << setprecision(6);

    double Y[] = {1., 0.};
    double xi0 = 0.1;
    double xif = 20.;
    double dxi = (xif-xi0)/Nmax;
    int neq =  1;

    ofstream fdata;
    fdata.open("lane_emden.dat");

    fdata << xi0 << " " << Y[0] << endl;
    cout << "xi: " << scientific << xi0 << "; theta: " << Y[0] << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<Nmax; i++){
    
        RK4Step(xi0, Y, dYdx, dZdx, dxi, neq);
        xi0 += dxi;

        fdata << xi0 << " " << Y[0] << endl;
        cout << "xi: " << scientific << xi0 << "; theta: " << Y[0] << "; f: " << Y[1] << endl;

    }
    fdata.close();



    return 0;
}


void RK4Step(double xi, double *Y, double (*dYdx)(double, double), double (*dZdx)(double, double, double), double dxi, int neq){

    double k1[2], k2[2], k3[2], k4[2];
    
    k1[0] = dYdx(xi, Y[0]);
    k1[1] = dZdx(xi, Y[0], Y[1]);

    k2[0] = dYdx(xi+dxi*0.5, Y[1] + k1[1]*0.5);
    k2[1] = dZdx(xi+dxi*0.5, Y[0] + k1[0]*0.5, Y[1] + k1[1]*0.5);

    k3[0] = dYdx(xi+dxi*0.5, Y[1] + k2[1]*0.5);
    k3[1] = dZdx(xi+dxi*0.5, Y[0] + k2[0]*0.5, Y[1] + k2[1]*0.5);

    k4[0] = dYdx(xi+dxi, Y[1] + k3[1]);
    k4[1] = dZdx(xi+dxi, Y[0] + k3[0], Y[1] + k3[1]);

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){Y[i] += (dxi/6.)*(k1[i] + 2*k2[i] + 2*k3[i] + k4[i]);}
}


double dYdx(double x, double Z){

    double dY = Z;
    return dY;
}

double dZdx(double xi, double Y, double Z){

    double dZ = - 1. - (2.*Z)/xi;
    return dZ;
}
```

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: @DavidJones If the output is wrong, this is not a good candidate for Code Review. Code Review is for questions where the code is correct, or at least has no trivial mistakes, but the asker wants to improve the code.

Comment: Is that the Lane-Edmen equation that looks something like  d/dx{x^2(dy/dx)}/x^2 + y^n = 0 ? Suggest you check the RK4 code out on damped simple harmonic motion to make sure it is working correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lane-emden solutions using RK4 (hard-coded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330621/lane-emden-solutions-using-rk4-hard-coded)

Answer (score 2):

You will find RK4 easier to use if it is set up to use array arguments, rather than multiple separate derivative functions. Here, I've used std::valarray, but I'm well aware that many programmers don't like that.

I've set n=1. The result is more interesting than n=0. For a comparison graph, see the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;

using vec = valarray<double>;

int n = 1;         // polytropic index

//======================================================================

double ipow( double x, int n ){ return n ? x * ipow( x, n - 1 ) : 1; }

//======================================================================

vec RK4step( double x, const vec &Y, vec f( double, const vec & ), double dx )
{
   vec dY1, dY2, dY3, dY4;
   dY1 = dx * f( x           , Y             );
   dY2 = dx * f( x + 0.5 * dx, Y + 0.5 * dY1 );
   dY3 = dx * f( x + 0.5 * dx, Y + 0.5 * dY2 );
   dY4 = dx * f( x +       dx, Y +       dY3 );
   return Y + ( dY1 + 2.0 * dY2 + 2.0 * dY3 + dY4 ) / 6.0;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   vec Y = { 1.0, 0.0 };
   int Nmax = 400;
   double xi0 = 0.01, xif = 20.0;
   double dxi = ( xif - xi0 ) / Nmax;
   auto deriv = []( double xi, const vec &Y ){ return vec{ Y[1], -2.0 / xi * Y[1] - ipow( Y[0], n ) }; };

   #define FMT scientific << setw( 12 ) << setprecision( 4 )
   ofstream fdata("lane_emden.dat");
// ostream &fdata = cout;

   double xi = xi0;
   fdata << FMT << "xi" << "  " << "theta" << '\n';
   fdata << FMT <<  xi  << "  " << Y[0]    << '\n';

   for ( int i = 1; i <= Nmax; i++ )
   {
      Y = RK4step( xi, Y, deriv, dxi );
      xi += dxi;
      fdata << FMT << xi << "  " << Y[0] << '\n';
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything seems to work nicely.